# Lookup Filter in some cases

Tags: lookup-filter

I have the search filter for an opportunity where I have 3 filters, but it only has to jump when the current record is at a specific stage. It's configured like this, but it doesn't work:

[image: current configuration]

any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! With the following configuration it works correctly (1 AND 2 AND3 AND 4) OR NOT(4)